# Is there any difference between both of these codes?

Tags: java

Assuming that I have a method that will always return a list with 0 or 1 objects: (never returns null)

```
public List<Object> getList() {

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    if (someCriteria) {
        list.add("1");
    }
    return list;
}
```

Is there any difference between both of these codes?

```
public Object getFirstElement() {
    List<Object> list = getList();
    return(getList().get(0));
}
```

versus

```
public Object getFirstElement() {
    List<Object> list = getList();
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)
        return list.get(0);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  You can see the differences.

Comment: Ignoring the syntax errors, calling `.get(0)` on a list with nothing in it will throw an index error of some sort.

Comment: Once again a simple trial run of the code would have shown the differences, is that too much to ask?

Comment: What kind of differences are you trying to figure out ? Clearly code does behave differently, but what is the aspect you are trying to compare : stability, maintenability, performance, number of lines, etc... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

In first case, if some creteria is false, `list` is an empty List:

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Test {

    boolean someCriteria = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().getFirstElement();
    }


    public List<Object> getList() {

        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        if (someCriteria) {
            list.add("1");
        }
        return list;
    }


    public Object getFirstElement() {
        List<Object> list = getList();
        return(getList().get(0));
    }
}
```

You get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Test.getFirstElement(Test.java:29)
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

in second case the funtion returns `null`.

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;


public class Test {

    boolean someCriteria = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Test().getFirstElement());
    }


    public List<Object> getList() {

        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        if (someCriteria) {
            list.add("1");
        }
        return list;
    }


        public Object getFirstElement() {
            List<Object> list = getList();
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list))
                return list.get(0);
            return null;
        }   
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
null
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you would get an OutOfBound exception if you attempt to access an item in the list that doesn't exist.